# SharePoint 2013 - make a choice in a column available only once

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 list for signing up for a certain event. I want to pre-populate it with available dates (I'm using the Choice column type) and have the users be able to choose a date and put their name in.

Is it possible to somehow validate the column so that when one date is taken the user can't select it anymore?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's bad design. You are trying to implement relations from wrong side. It's 1-* relation and you want to store the information on the left side of the relations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, fdafadf. I don't understand, can you clarify?